# Which layout is a .phtml file using

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, magento-community, phtml, register

My registration page is using a `register.phtml` located under certain path, which I know. But I don't know where the associated xml layout file is located, because it was already defined and I didn't do it.

But I want to use another `.phtml` file. My problem is that I am not able to find which layout is defining the `.phtml` that will be used. Or at least, the one it's supposed to be seems not to be the one that's being used.

I have been trying without success to obtain the layout that's being used. I tried using

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_form_register')->getXml(); ?>
```

and some similar things, but without success. I already activated from the admin the path and block hints.

I need to know which layout is defining the used `register.phtml`. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In customer.xml check the following handle :

```
<customer_account_create translate="label">
    <label>Customer Account Registration Form</label>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                <label>Form Fields Before</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Comment: Indeed this handle is defined as you point out, but it seems that is being overwritten by another layout file.

Comment: try to search **customer_form_register** in all custom layout files by using any editor if is there any reference for this block.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment if your `register.phtml` overwritten by another module then just put this code :

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName(); ?>
```

in your `register.phtml` and refresh the frontend this will tell you the module name find that module config file  it will be locate in either `app/code/local` or `app/code/community` and then open the `config.xml` of that module it will be `app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/etc/` folder then open that file and find this node `<layout>` here you can get the xml file name

Answer (score 0):

if you want set another `phtml` file you dont need to modify existing code

you can use `setTemplate` for override default template  for that use below code in your themes `local.xml` file

```
<customer_account_create translate="label">
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>myphtmlPath/myphtml.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```